# "Source" parameter of the "MIDL" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, migration

I am trying to migrate one of projects earlier in VS2008 to VS2010. On building I get the following error

C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(317,7): error MSB4094: "hdxBinding.idl;hdxBlinking.idl;HDXCommandObject.idl;hdxds.idl;HSCProcessStatus.idl;HSCSelectableWindow.idl" is an invalid value for the "Source" parameter of the "MIDL" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".

On clicking this error, it takes me to the line  Source    ="@(Midl)" inside C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets file

A Code Snippet in Microsoft.CppCommon.targets file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Midl Condition="'@(Midl)' != ''">
    <MinimalRebuildFromTracking   Condition="'$(BuildType)' != 'Build' or '$(ForceRebuild)' == 'true'">false</MinimalRebuildFromTracking>
  </Midl>
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <MidlToolArchitecture Condition="'$(MidlToolArchitecture)' == ''">$(DefaultToolArchitecture)</MidlToolArchitecture>
</PropertyGroup>

<MIDL
  Condition                           ="'%(Midl.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true'"
  Source                              ="@(Midl)"

  AdditionalIncludeDirectories        ="%(Midl.AdditionalIncludeDirectories)"
  AdditionalOptions                   ="%(Midl.AdditionalOptions)"
  ApplicationConfigurationMode        ="%(Midl.ApplicationConfigurationMode)"
  ClientStubFile                      ="%(Midl.ClientStubFile)"
  CPreprocessOptions                  ="%(Midl.CPreprocessOptions)"
  DefaultCharType                     ="%(Midl.DefaultCharType)"
  DllDataFileName                     ="%(Midl.DllDataFileName)"
  EnableErrorChecks                   ="%(Midl.EnableErrorChecks)"
  ErrorCheckAllocations               ="%(Midl.ErrorCheckAllocations)"
  ErrorCheckBounds                    ="%(Midl.ErrorCheckBounds)"
  ErrorCheckEnumRange                 ="%(Midl.ErrorCheckEnumRange)"
  ErrorCheckRefPointers               ="%(Midl.ErrorCheckRefPointers)"
  ErrorCheckStubData                  ="%(Midl.ErrorCheckStubData)"
  ExcludedInputPaths                  ="$(ExcludePath)"
  GenerateClientFiles                 ="%(Midl.GenerateClientFiles)"
  GenerateServerFiles                 ="%(Midl.GenerateServerFiles)"
  GenerateStublessProxies             ="%(Midl.GenerateStublessProxies)"
  GenerateTypeLibrary                 ="%(Midl.GenerateTypeLibrary)"
  HeaderFileName                      ="%(Midl.HeaderFileName)"
  IgnoreStandardIncludePath           ="%(Midl.IgnoreStandardIncludePath)"
  InterfaceIdentifierFileName         ="%(Midl.InterfaceIdentifierFileName)"
  LocaleID                            ="%(Midl.LocaleID)"
  MkTypLibCompatible                  ="%(Midl.MkTypLibCompatible)"
  OutputDirectory                     ="%(Midl.OutputDirectory)"
  PreprocessorDefinitions             ="%(Midl.PreprocessorDefinitions)"
  ProxyFileName                       ="%(Midl.ProxyFileName)"
  RedirectOutputAndErrors             ="%(Midl.RedirectOutputAndErrors)"
  ServerStubFile                      ="%(Midl.ServerStubFile)"
  StructMemberAlignment               ="%(Midl.StructMemberAlignment)"
  SuppressCompilerWarnings            ="%(Midl.SuppressCompilerWarnings)"
  SuppressStartupBanner               ="%(Midl.SuppressStartupBanner)"
  TargetEnvironment                   ="%(Midl.TargetEnvironment)"
  TypeLibFormat                       ="%(Midl.TypeLibFormat)"
  TypeLibraryName                     ="%(Midl.TypeLibraryName)"
  UndefinePreprocessorDefinitions     ="%(Midl.UndefinePreprocessorDefinitions)"
  ValidateAllParameters               ="%(Midl.ValidateAllParameters)"
  WarnAsError                         ="%(Midl.WarnAsError)"
  WarningLevel                        ="%(Midl.WarningLevel)"

  TrackerLogDirectory                 ="%(Midl.TrackerLogDirectory)"
  MinimalRebuildFromTracking          ="%(Midl.MinimalRebuildFromTracking)"
  ToolArchitecture                    ="$(MidlToolArchitecture)"
  TrackerFrameworkPath                ="$(MidlTrackerFrameworkPath)"
  TrackerSdkPath                      ="$(MidlTrackerSdkPath)"

  TLogReadFiles                       ="@(MIDLTLogReadFiles)"
  TLogWriteFiles                      ="@(MIDLTLogWriteFiles)"
  ToolExe                             ="$(MIDLToolExe)"
  ToolPath                            ="$(MIDLToolPath)"
  TrackFileAccess                     ="$(TrackFileAccess)"

  AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes          ="%(Midl.AcceptableNonZeroExitCodes)"
  YieldDuringToolExecution            ="$(MidlYieldDuringToolExecution)"
  >
</MIDL>
```

Can somebody please tell me whats going wrong here. This is driving me crazy!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Got a similar error today on a project that I am converting to VS2010.  I don't have a good solution to the problem yet, but I have a workaround.  In my case, the project contained 2 idl files.  Call them A.idl and B.idl.  A.idl is the main idl for the project.  It includes B.Idl.  The error I received was:

error MSB4094: "A.idl;B.idl" is an invalid value for the "Source" parameter of the "MIDL" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".

It seems that the build system searched for all idl files in the project and made a single call to the MIDL compiler with all of them even though that was bound to fail.  I don't know why VS2010 does that and earlier version didn't (or maybe earlier versions of MIDL could handle multiple inputs).

The workaround: grab the MIDL arguments off of MIDL Command Line page of the project's properties.  Then run MIDL by hand in a VS2010 Command Prompt window using those args.  In my case, since A.idl includes B.idl, I only needed to run one MIDL command:

MIDL options-copied-from-project-properties A.IDL

It looks like you have multiple idl files in your project (hdxBinding.idl, hdxBlinking.idl, etc.).  So the same trick might work for you.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue trying to build the DataMonitor example from the TMG SDK with Visual Studio 2010. The problem from what I can tell is the MIDL > Output settings in the project - the Header File, IID File, Proxy File, and Type Library were set to "DataMonitor...", which was forcing those settings to be applied to all included IDL files (and not just the project's generated one).

Changing those settings to use %(Filename) instead and the project built fine.

Answer (score 1):

When there are multiple IDL files in the project I converted from VS 2008 to VS 2010, I got this error. Since one IDL I had was included in the other. I disabled building of the included IDL file and it resolved this error.

Answer (score 0):

These errors prop up when migrating to VS2010 as the .idl file properties are not migrated by VS2010 migrator. I got a similar error and resolved this by manually adding these parameters from to VS2010. Once done you will be able to get rid of these build errors.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem as well. The fix was (very confusing) remove empty  in the vcxproj file. I run out of time and have not got to the bottom of why it helps - defining not empty HeaderFileName fixes the problem as well, other empty elements do not cause this problem (e.g. DllDataFileName). 
If you want to reproduce bug or process of my investigation just create hello world and add two idl files. It should work. However if you add ItemGroupDefinition with Midl.HeaderFileName it should start failing. One wild guess is that it has something to do with batching of tasks (working example calls MIDL task for each file separately).