# Using C++ namespaces in IDL files when declaring interfaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, declaration, idl

I have a library written in C++ and I want to use structures from it when declaring interfaces in IDL file. Here is the sample:

service.idl

```
import "..//core//common_structures.h";
[
  object,
  uuid(13B01AEB-52EC-4546-BDE0-DE91B37337CE),
  dual,
  pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IDeviceManagement: IUnknown {
   HRESULT GetSerialByIndex  ([in] uint8_t id, [out] Serial *serial, [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL *result);
};
```

Serial structure is defined in imported header under key_api namespace. When building everything goes ok until service_i.h is generated and the following error appears:

```
 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Serial'    ..\service\service_i.h
```

near these generated lines:

```
IDeviceManagement : public IUnknown
{
public:        
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetSerialByIndex( 
        /* [in] */ uint8_t id,
        /* [out] */ Serial *serial,
        /* [retval][out] */ VARIANT_BOOL *result) = 0;
};
```

I think it's because of Serial is wrapped under the namespace and service_i.h doesn't know anything about it. One solution is just to get rid of namespace. Is there any variant when we can actually keep the namespace?

Comment: You're IDL-importing a *header*; not an IDL file. `Serial` should be described in another IDL filer described in *this* IDL file using (what else) IDL. this is particularly important in the case you're trying to use it, as the proxy/stub generator needs to know how `Serial` is laid out for marshaling.

Comment: When I add one more IDL file, VS2010 throws an error:
error MSB4094: "service.idl;structures.idl" is an invalid value for the "Source" parameter of the "MIDL" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem". C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 317

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Source" parameter of the "MIDL" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287885/source-parameter-of-the-midl-task-multiple-items-cannot-be-passed-into-a-pa)